# ¿Cómo añado los valores de un ListView en un TextBox/ComboBox? VB6

Tags: botón, combobox, vb6, textbox

Tengo esta interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ingreso datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se cargan en el `ListView`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que al hacerle doble click a un item cargado de la lista, este se vuelva hacia arriba con los valores con los que fue cargado. Es decir, doy doble click al item de la lista, este debe cargar los valores del `ComboBox`, `TextBox`, `CheckBox` con los que fue añadido al `Listview`. Esto sería para que en caso de que el usuario haya cargado mal un dato, este pueda editarlo dando doble click.

Pensé en esto pero no ha funcionado:

```
Private Sub List_Contactos_DblClick()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To List_Contactos.ListItems.Count
    List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(1) = CmbTipoTel.Text
    List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(2) = MebPreFijo.Text
    List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(3) = txttel.Text
    List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(4) = ChPrincipal.value
    List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(5) = ChVinculo.value
Next i

End Sub
```

¿Sugerencias?

Comment: No es exactamente tu mismo codigo, pero al reves?

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. ¿Puedes añadir una respuesta de ejemplo? Digo, para no tener que borrar la pregunta. @gbianchi

Comment: Podes agregar vos mismo la respuesta y luego de pasadas 24 hs aceptarla...

Comment: Oh, sí. Al final, la respuesta que puse no funciona del todo bien porque sale error en el índice. @gbianchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respueta:

```
Private Sub List_Contactos_DblClick()

Dim i As Integer
Dim IntPrincipal As Integer
Dim IntVinculo As Integer
Dim IntTipo As Integer

If MebPreFijo.Text = "" And txttel.Text = "" Then
        'For i = 1 To List_Contactos.ListItems.Count

        'CmbTipoTel


'        If List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(1) = "Fijo" Then
'            IntTipo = 1
'        Else
'            IntTipo = 2
'        End If
        CmbTipoTel.Text = List_Contactos.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)

        'MebPreFijo
        MebPreFijo.Text = List_Contactos.SelectedItem.SubItems(2)

        'txttel
        txttel.Text = List_Contactos.SelectedItem.SubItems(3)

        'CheckPrincipal
        If List_Contactos.SelectedItem.SubItems(4) = "SI" Then
            IntPrincipal = 1
        Else
            IntPrincipal = 0
        End If
        ChPrincipal.value = IntPrincipal

        'ComboTipoVinculo
        If List_Contactos.SelectedItem.SubItems(5) = "" Then
            IntVinculo = 0
        Else
            Rs.Open "select tv_id from dbo.Tipo_Vinculo where tv_descripcion='" & List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(5) & "'", Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
            IntVinculo = Rs!TV_Id
            Rs.Close
        End If
        ChVinculo.value = IntVinculo

        'Limpiar ese item
        List_Contactos.ListItems.Remove List_Contactos.SelectedItem.Index

    'Next i

    Else
    MsgBox "Tiene datos que se pueden perder. Por favor, presione añadir."

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Este codigo no es correcto. Porque recorres toda la lista en lugar de usar solo el item seleccionado? porque borras el item de la lista?

Comment: Al ciclo for, ya lo quité. Y borro el item de la lista porque así me lo pidieron

Comment: Pero este codigo no funciona.. i no tiene valor?

Comment: Oh, que ya lo cambié. Pero, resulta que al hacer doble click me manda cualquier item

Comment: Como que te manda cualquier item? este codigo termina funcionando o no?

Comment: Para hacerlo resumido, si añado dos items a la lista y hago doble click sobre el segundo me carga el primero.

Comment: el doble click no debe estar seleccionando el segundo item ;) no recuero tanto de vb como para acordarme el orden de ejecucion de los eventos.. pero tal vez, doble click no te sirve? se que con un click anda...

Comment: Tenes la lista para que solo permita seleccionar un item? o la tenes para multiples?

Comment: para que seleccione un solo ítem

Comment: Entonces el doble deberia marcar el item donde haces click.. vos lo ves seleccionado al hacer doble click?